# how to Merge 2 tables with awk

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

First of all, sorry for my English and I know there's a lot of various topics regarding AWK but it's a very difficult function to me...
I would like to merge two tables using common columns with awk. The tables differ in the amount of rows. I have my first table that I want to modify and the second as a reference table. I would like to compare my `colunme1.F1` with my `column1.F2`. When it matches, add the `column2.F2` in my `file1`. But I need to keep all my lines in `file1`.

I give you an example:

File1

```
Num_id,Name,description1,description2,description3
?,atlanta_1,,,      
RO_5,babeni_SW,,,           
? ,Bib1,,,          
RO_9,BoUba_456,,,           
?,Castor,,,
```

File2

```
official_Num_id,official_Name
RO_1,America
RO_2,Andre
RO_3,Atlanta
RO_4,Axa
RO_5,Babeni
RO_6,Barba
RO_7,Bib
RO_8,Bilbao
RO_9,Bouba
RO_10,Castor
```

File3

```
Num_id,Name,description1,description2,description3,official_Name
?,atlanta_1,,,
RO_5,babeni_SW,,,Babeni
?,Bib1,,,
RO_9,BoUba_456,,,Bouba
?,Castor,,,
```

I read a lot of solution on Internet and it seems that awk could work ..
I tried `awk 'NR==FNR {h[$1] = $2; next} {print $0,h[$1]}' $File1 $File2 > file3`
But my command doesn't work, my `File3` looks exactly that `File1`.

In a second time, I don't know if it's possible to compare my two second columns when names have difference like atlanta_1 and Atlanta and add the official_num_id and the official_name in my File1.

Any hero over there?

Comment: The comma count in `file3` is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had it, except for two small things. First you need to set your file separators to `,` and, second, reverse the order of your input files on the command line so that the reference file is processed first:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} NR==FNR {h[$1] = $2; next} {print $0,h[$1]}' File2 File1
Num_id,Name,description1,description2,description3,
?,atlanta_1,,,,
RO_5,babeni_SW,,,,Babeni
? ,Bib1,,,,
RO_9,BoUba_456,,,,Bouba
?,Castor,,,,
```

Comment: Thank you, It works !!! In fact I have ";" and not "," I haven't noticed that before your post.. Something I don't understand, my 4th columns doesn't appear as a 4th column but inside my second colunm as a new line when it matches... any idea why ?

Comment: I found why, it was because of the character ^M in my output file. Using awk -v RS='\r\n' ... resolves my problem

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the join command for this:

```
 join --header  --nocheck-order -t, -1 1 -2 1 -a 1 file1 file2
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question *if it's possible to compare my two second columns when names have difference like atlanta_1 and Atlanta and add the official_num_id and the official_name in my File1*:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
NR==FNR {                                                  # file2
    a[tolower($2)]=$0                                      # hash on lowercase city
    next
}
{                                                          # file1
    split($2,b,"[^[:alpha:]]")                             # split on non-alphabet
    print $0 (tolower(b[1]) in a?OFS a[tolower(b[1])]:"")  
}' file2 file1 
Num_id,Name,description1,description2,description3
?,atlanta_1,,,,RO_3,Atlanta
RO_5,babeni_SW,,,,RO_5,Babeni
? ,Bib1,,,,RO_7,Bib
RO_9,BoUba_456,,,,RO_9,Bouba
?,Castor,,,,RO_10,Castor
```

`split` will split `Name` field on non-alphabetic characters, ie `_` in `atlanta_1`, `1` in `Bib1` etc. so it might fail on cities with dashes etc., edit the pattern `[^[:alpha:]]` in `split` accordingly. Header doesn't match with those names, rethink the header names.

Comment: Thank you very much.!! It's very hepfull !!! could you explain me a little bit the second part after split. I understood the concept but not each parameter..!! You told me also that I will have issues if name has dash. And if I have space like babani SW, I will have the same prob? In fact, the goal is to standardize all names so I can find lots of differents cases..!!

Comment: As the `split` splits @ any non-alphabetic character (currently, with above code), for example Belgian city Knokke-Heist (thanks Wiki) would be split incorrectly to just Knokke. You could circumvent that by adding - to the `[^[:alpha:]-]` but can't use that as a special character anymore. If there are cities with space in their names, that will produce faulty output as well. Just test it.

Comment: With _second part_ I assume you meant the `print`. It prints the current record (`$0`) from `file1`, converts to lower case the first part of the `split`ted city name (for example babani), looks for it in the hash of `file2` and if found, outputs it after the `$0`. It's called _conditional operator_: `( if true ? then return this : else this )`.